# Render HTML text the same across all browsers?

Tags: html, css, text

I've been tasked with making an editorial page, similar to a newspaper article.

**I've fiddled it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/dp3tn9sx/

My issue is that it looks great on Chrome, but on Firefox I have a few stray words which unforunately ruin the look and feel of the page

**Here are screenshots:**

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Is there anything I can do in my markup that would make this look how I expect it to (Chrome) across all browsers?  This is mostly, position absolute and justified text

```
#container p {position: absolute; margin: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 14px;}
.textBlock1 {left: 110px; top: 48px; width: 420px}
```

Or are there any solutions to achieve this sort of look using another method?!

Comment: Use a css reset, it could help ;)

Comment: Many browsers have very slight differences in things like default line height, letter spacing, word spacing, and default fonts. As Veve said, a "CSS reset file" normalizes all browsers to a reasonable default for most of those, and may help you out. It's possible you'll run into more trouble if you want compatibility with old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can't see the issue you describe in FF..

Comment: @Nick: no, browsers render font by their internal rules, you can´t achive the same view in different browsers. Sure, for any font-variants (family, size, color) the view could be almost the same, but it´s in a minimum cases. It depends on browser, browser version, platform (win vs. unix vs. mac), ...